# Create a Visual Studio type look using Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I would like to create extend a Java Swing application to have a look somewhat similar to an IDE such as Eclipse or Visual Studio.  That’s, there would be a panel at the left that displays a tree, and a tab panel on the right that allows several elements of the tree to be opened and edited on right.  For this I could easily use a BorderLayout and just use the center and left areas.

However, I would also like to have the ability for the user to drag the border between these two panels, just like Eclipse and Visual Studio allow.  I can think of several ways to do this, but was curious if anyone had found a particularly good way to do this, or knew of an example.  I’ve googled for it, but have not found anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [JSplitPane](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/splitpane.html). And maybe have a look at an article about a [MultiSplitPane](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/03/23/multi-split-pane.html).

Comment: Thanks! Not sure how I missed JSplitPane.  Looks like it will do just what I need.

Answer (score 2):

While JSplitPane does exactly what you asked for, you might also be interested in JToolBar, which does other Eclipse-like things such as attach/detach and drag a panel of tools around the UI.